# Rounded Stackpanel corners

Tags: xaml

I am trying to round the corners of the stackpanel in this design for a login portal. I can't seem to work out how to do this! There is some content within this panel I have missed out to reduce the length in Code!

Is there an obvious way to do this which I am missing?

```
`<StackPanel Width="315"
             Grid.Row="3"
             Background="#FFFFFF"
             Orientation="Vertical">
</StackPanel>`
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would be to put the 'StackPanel' inside a 'Border'

```
    <Border Background="Pink" CornerRadius="15"
            BorderThickness="2"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            Padding="5"
            Grid.Row="3">

        <StackPanel Width="315"
            Orientation="Vertical">

        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
```